# VBScript CStr function

Tags: vbscript, type-conversion

I'm using the conversion function CStr in VBScript to convert a number of type Long into a String. The problem is after converting to a string the decimal point is lost eg 2.5 is converted to 2.

Does anyone know a way to preserve the decimal point using this conversion function?

Many Thanks,

Comment: A Long type can't have a decimal portion, it's an integer. Can you post us some code? I'll bet the farm `CStr` isn't the problem here, and we'll need to see some code that exhibits the problem to tell you what the problem, and its solution is.

Comment: Umm, VBScript only has one data type: `Variant`. The only way to answer this question is to see the code that isn't behaving as you expect.

Comment: @Cody Gray. That is not true. Only you cannot declare a variable as a certain type, but if you use "VarType()", you can see what type of datatype a variable is. That datatype is also used by the VBScript interpreter.

Comment: @Automated: Yeah, there's an underlying type. But if you assign a numeric literal like `2.5` to a variable, it will automatically create a floating point type. The question doesn't mention anything about `VarType`, and it's really difficult to answer something like this without any source code.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You are right that the question would be more clear if it includes the source code. And you are right that VBScript auto types the data (in some systems however, it would convert 2.5 to a string, the strange country I live in uses the comma as a decimal separator for example). Though, the statement "VBScript has only one data type: `Variant`" was not fully correct, so I felt the urge to react on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably that casting the number to Long is the problem as long is just a type that will contains bigger integers, and does not support decimals.

Maybe try a currency, single or double type for the numeric value before doing the CStr

Answer (score 1):

Have you echoed out your CLng variable?  CLng rounds decimals to the nearest even number so it is likely the CLng which is rounding your decimal places rather than CStr dropping them.  Can you use CDbl rather than CLng?